# Can I store a reference to a local reference?

Tags: c#, reference, pointer-to-pointer

To be clear, I want the behavior of a pointer-to-a-pointer, and the purpose of this question is to generate clean, readable code.

I have some code that contains conditions checking the result of multiple `Dictionary.TryGetValue` calls. It would be cleaner if it could retrieve all of the required objects with a single call, so I wanted to write an extension that will allow me to do the following:

```
Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary; // Initialized somewhere

string x, y, z;
bool foundAllEntries = myDictionary.TryGetValues({"xvalue", out x}, {"yvalue", out y}, 
    {"zvalue", out z});
if (foundAllEntries)
    ; // Do something with x, y, and z
```

However, I can't figure out a way to pass the extension method references to the objects that will hold the output. This seems like something that should be very basic.

How can I store a reference to a local reference in an object?

**Please note that this question is not asking for alternative approaches to implementing the TryGetValues function.** There are many ways I can make this 'work,' but none generate code as clean as the approach I'm trying to take.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "the extension method references". The code you've given will definitely not work for any implementation of `TryGetValues`... it's not clear to me what you'd expect that to look like in terms of its signature. (I can think of some alternative approaches which *would* work, admittedly - but you've said you don't want those, so all I can say is that the code you've got simply won't compile whatever you do.)

Comment: `TryGetValues` isn't implemented, it's an extension I want to write. I can't figure out a signature that will perform as I expect. Does C# really not support something as basic as a reference to a reference? Also, I think you mis-read, based on the quote. You cut out some important words there.

Comment: Well you can certainly use `out` and `ref` parameters with reference types, if that's what you're asking. But I can't tell what signature you're trying to implement, which makes it very hard to tell whether what you're really looking for is supported or not. Forget the *implementation* for the moment - work out what the *signature* would look like. (I'd personally use method chaining rather than a single call, but hey...)

Comment: @JonSkeet: I essentially want `bool TryGetValues(this Dictionary<K,V> dict, params Pair<K, out V>[] requests)`. It obviously isn't possible to use `out` or `ref` here, however.

Comment: Right, so you're trying to use `out` with `Pair` - that won't work, because `out` isn't part of the type itself in a way that allows you to specify it in a type argument. (It's a parameter modifier, not part of the type.) That's certainly not something that bothers me - but as I say, I wouldn't try to solve the problem this way anyway.

Comment: I think there is a flaw in your design. Either make a lot of extension methods with an overload for every extra new set, or chain the calls, like Jon suggested.

Comment: The syntax I'd use would end up with something like `if (dict.TryGetValues("xvalue", out x).And("yvalue", out y).And("zvalue", out z).AllFound)`

Comment: If that's too complicated to implement, perhaps create overloads for `(T val1, out x)`, `(T val1, out x, T val2, out y)`, `(T val1, out x, T val2, out y, T val3, out z)`, etc.  Perhaps up to ten or so.  If you needed more than that, just call it twice.  Personally, I like @JonSkeet's implementation best..

Comment: @Mike replace `string` with a generic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> This seems like something that should be very basic.

Not only it isn't basic, it's outright impossible: there is no way to decorate a data type with `ref` or `out` - these modifiers are applicable exclusively to formal method parameters. In other words, there is no such thing as a "reference variable" or an "output variable"; there are only "reference parameters" and "output parameters" in the language.

Moreover, you cannot pass output or by reference parameters as part of a variable-length argument list (i.e. the `params` portion) so that approach wouldn't work either.

> There are many ways I can make this 'work,' but none generate code as clean as the approach I'm trying to take.

Curiously, the above does not mean that you cannot implement the scheme that you are trying to implement, leaving the code nearly as clean as your original one if you apply the [Proxy Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern). The trick is to chain method calls, and provide an implicit conversion operator for the result, like this:

```
class MyMap {
    internal IDictionary<string,string> dict = ...
    public ItemGetterResult TryGetValues {
        get {
            return new ItemGetterResult(this, true);
        }
    }
}

class ItemGetterResult {
    private readonly MyMap map;
    private bool IsSuccessful {get;set;}
    internal ItemGetterResult(MyMap theMap, bool successFlag) {
        map = theMap;
        IsSuccessful = successFlag;
    }
    public static implicit operator bool(ItemGetterResult r) {
        return r.IsSuccessful;
    }
    public ItemGetterResult Get(string key, out string val) {
        return new ItemGetterResult(
            map
        ,   this.IsSuccessful && map.dict.TryGetValue(key, out val)
        );
    }
}
```

Now the call looks like this:

```
bool foundAllEntries = myDictionary.TryGetValues
    .Get("xvalue", out x)
    .Get("yvalue", out y)
    .Get("zvalue", out z);
```

Comment: `+1` for the implicit conversion to bool.  Handy.

Comment: An indexer could perhaps make it more funky ;p

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mutable `Reference` type:

```
public class Reference<T>
{
    public T Value;
}

/* declaration */
bool TryGetValues(
    this Dictionary<K,V> dict,
    params Tuple<K, Reference<V>>[] requests)

/* call site */
var x = new Reference<string>();
var y = new Reference<string>();
var z = new Reference<string>();
bool foundAllEntries = myDictionary.TryGetValues(
    Tuple.Create("xvalue", x),
    Tuple.Create("yvalue", y), 
    Tuple.Create("zvalue", z));
```